# Смена кодировки

Tags: javascript, steam, steam-web-api, decode

После запроса к steam api на ноде с помощью модуля "request" я получаю примерно следующий результат:

`` \n' +
    "��[��c�b�����H���\rֱ�;��嫓\u0002?���Z\u0000�\u0010��r�\u0016��=ץ��:)��tm�W'�\u0003�#XE\f�G�\u0010�2�3�1:�\u0019eQ��Q[��Kq��5X'�ut�/�v\n" +
    '���4\u0002��[E�Jo��Oq�i��Jl��+�\u001c�Rȟ_�\u001a�5D��K>��G�~��\u001c\u0003��[<���]�\u001a*�C��\u0018����,�\u0007t��y�,�Qe ���{�\u0000�g��\u0003���ع���C�U�\u001a\u0010C�\u0012��1*�[\u0001�\u0006�Tÿ�\u0016d ���Q��L\u0003�Ƃ{\u000bV\u0011�ڵ=�9��\f\u000b8~\u0014�_mW\\�o\u0001�$\u0002\'�4�l6��\f�epf�9��\u0006�28����\u0017�XUά��xL3����\r��q��m�\u0000s�\u0003�<w�U�ϏvO�XU�\u001fl:\u0011�D������\u000b��l~���Sz��zO\u0001=��e�m��i�\u0019t�q�1-\f�"��#����@�y(�M�\u0002��y�:��Ӭͫ�\u0019�����������y�}1��Ř��?\r�[�H#X��3Z�N\'�Ơ-\u001ddj�c���\u001b\u0004�W��\u0007D�\b�PW�\u000b\'\u0012j������~������d�cW+ө�\r\b07=:t�L�\u001d��q0\u0003)��V�B;ë�i�����!"t���\u001a��5�\u001d�5\u0010�\|_OٳX���/�y�\u0004.��L�\u0013�,�o�\u0011$k\bv��\�LO"2s��\u001a�+�2|\n' +
    " ʬx\u001a�y9�Y�j�����\u0003���^\u0016���6/)Lz���+��Y�1�kc��4Ԉ\u001c�Y�9ǆ:\u001dv}L�)��\u0010�݈糐�y]�Lϓ\u0019�\u0014`�g5\u0018�^bTk&�t(v�Lu��;\u0016\u000fye^I��\f��}�Ne\'SY�>}\u0004'\u0012��l\u0007=Flj�n�� F�1\u0014�%FŘ\z�Ɇ\u001e�\u0007\'S�-����:���\u001b1��������f��Z�S7\u0018:?7i0Ü�����ry��c,�s\u000e�#v��<8��U�\u001a���^ML\u000f$�hv�1��|�Q��c���6\r����\f\bV!ML�\u0001�hD�y��bju��<�\u00157�0\n" +
    '$\n' + ``

Пожалуйста, подскажите каким образом можно декодировать это?

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вдруг у кого возникнет подобная проблема, достаточно добавить `gzip: true` в ваш request запрос.

Должно быть что-то на подобии:

```
request({method: "GET", encoding: null, gzip: true, url: link, headers} ...
```